# GWT / Hibernate NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, gwt

Trying to figure out this NullPointerException.  I have a GWT 2.5 project that uses Hibernate 3.  Right now the application works when calling stored procedures through hibernate, but when saving a new entity using Session.save() and I get an error.

I cant figure out what's null.  I'm currently not using validation in the bean and I made sure that all fields have a default value in the entity, so there are no null fields.

Is anyone familiar with this type of error?   I'd have to get permission to post code for the project but anything to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    at $Proxy33.save(Unknown Source)
    at org.afscme.outreach.external.server.ConferenceServiceImpl.saveReservation(ConferenceServiceImpl.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

**UPDATE #1:**

Libraries:
Thanks for the reponse @ChrisHinshaw. I have the following libraries included:

- hibernate3
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0-Final
- gwt-validation-2.1
- antlr-2.7.6
- slf4j-api-1.6.6
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6-sources
- slf4j-simple-1.6.6
- commons-collections-3.1
- dom4j-1.6.1
- javassist-3.12.0.GA
- jta-1.1
- jtds-1.2.5

... the rest are GWT-relted jars.

Comment: Do you have the hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar in your classpath. This looks like it may be a validator problem.

Comment: I threw in hibernate-validator and am still getting the same issue (I tried with hibernate-validator-3 and hibernate-validator-4. You may be right about it being a library issue.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but it seems to work fine when I deploy to jboss.  must be an issue with my libraries/hosted mode.  I'll look into the cause later, for now I'll test outside of hosted mode.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error:

The solution was for me to clear the WEB-INF/lib directory and a complete refresh of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors when I placed the Hibernate libraries in a folder inside the libs directory i.e. lib/hibernate/. Try to place them in /lib if that's the case.